# issue with max function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select i.description, p.cost, i.itemid,p.dateq as datessss 
from item i, (select itemid,max(date) as dateq,cost 
              from price group by itemid) p
WHERE i.itemid = p.itemid 



description        cost    itemid    datessss
ChickenRatePerKG   108     26        2015-03-02
LiveBird           55.25   27        2015-03-02
Eggs               197     28        2015-03-02
```

This is my price table

```
itemid     date          cost
28         2015-03-02    450
28         2015-02-14    380
28         2015-02-13    200
28         2015-02-01    400
28         2014-01-23    197
28         2014-01-22    197
```

It is fetching the right date but not the price corresponding to the date.

Can someone please help me with finding the issue?

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: cost of eggs should be 450 when the date modified is 2015-03-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in different ways, using `left join` or using `not exists` or a `correlated sub query`

```
select
i.description,
i.itemid,
p.cost,
p.date as datessss
from item i
join price p on p.itemid = i.itemid
left join price p1 on p1.itemid = p.itemid and p1.date > p.date
where p1.itemid is null ;
```

OR

```
select
i.description,
i.itemid,
p.cost,
p.date as datessss
from item i
join price p on p.itemid = i.itemid
where not exists
(
  select 1 from price p1
  where p1.itemid = p.itemid and p1.date > p.date
)
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de026/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
select i.description, p.cost, i.itemid,p.dateq as datessss 
from item i, (select itemid,max(date) as dateq,cost 
              from price group by itemid having date=max(date)) p
WHERE i.itemid = p.itemid
```

Without `having` you don't know which row you get.